# Assure correct string input in C++

Tags: c++, string, format, stdstring, istream

I'm trying to assure that my input string is correctly formated (correct format XXX-X-XXX ),but I don't wan't to use char temp[255] and cin.getline combination.

So far I've managed to "catch" all exceptions besides this one:

*Enter registration plate*: shjkf 22h 23jfh3kfh jkfhsdj h2j h2k **123-A-456**

As assumed regPlate will get all the strings from the input including the correct formated one at the end and it will print the string.That's not correct. After reading the first string it should print Bad input and everything after it needs to be deleted.

I've tried to use `cin.clear()`,`cin.ignore()`,etc. in my *if* function but with no results.

```
void main()
{
    std::string regPlate;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter registration plate: ";
        cin >> regPlate;
        if (regPlate.size() < 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-' || regPlate.size() > 9)
        {
            cout << "Bad entry" << endl;

        }
    } while (regPlate.size() < 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-' || regPlate.size() > 9);
    cout << endl << regPlate << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check for size being smaller than `9` *and* larger than `9`. Just have a single check for size not equal to `9`.

Comment: As for your problem, are you perhaps looking for [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "but I don't wan't to use char temp[255] and cin.getline combination."

Comment: @BrunoFerreira [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) are two different things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you can assume that the OP doesn't want any `getline`s at all.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Well that *is* the best way to read and possibly discard a whole line of input.

Comment: To the OP can you actually *show* some of your failed attempts? And please if possible elaborate on what's wrong with the input you show and how it should be handled. Should the input be valid if the *only* input is e.g. `123-A-456` with nothing else on the line before or after?

Comment: Also, if you want to make sure that you actually get digits when only digits are allowed and you get letter when only letters are allowed (and that the upper versus lower case is correct) then you might want to look into the C++ [regular expression standard functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: Only correct input is in this format **XXX-X-XXX*  not any other character/string before or after that.

Comment: This works just fine for me: http://ideone.com/KtaDSJ

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude **std::getline** worked. Didn't knew that this method exists,I've thought that only getline is from istream
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would a while loop work, maybe something like:

```
int main(){
    string regPlate;
    while(regPlate.size() != 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-'){
        cout << "Enter registration plate: " << endl;
        cin >> regPlate;
    }
    cout << regPlate;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you provide (with a few assumptions) I ran your code an it seems to work as expected. Here's what I ran, with the headers included.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
   string regPlate;
   do
   {
       cout << "Enter registration plate: ";
       cin >> regPlate;
       if (regPlate.size() != 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-')
       {
          cout << "Bad entry" << endl;

       }
   } while (regPlate.size() != 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-');
   cout << endl << regPlate << endl;

   system("pause");
}
```

The output I receive is:

```
Enter registration plate: shjkf 22h 23jfh3kfh jkfhsdj h2j h2k 123-A-456
Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: Bad Entry
Enter registration plate: 
123-A-456
```

I also manually typed out all of the values your listed, and it appeared to work that way also.

Comment: That input is invalid.
I've fixed the problem,but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Someprogrammerdude I've managed to fix the problem.

Only thing that I've had to do is instead of `std::cin>>regPlate` to use `std::getline(cin,regPlate)`

```
std::string regPlate;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter registration plate: ";
        std::getline(cin, regPlate);
        if (regPlate.size() != 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-')
        {
            cout << "Bad entry" << endl;

        }
    } while (regPlate.size() != 9 || regPlate.at(3) != '-' || regPlate.at(5) != '-');
    cout << regPlate << endl;
```